# Getting the status of all checkboxes in webform populated by mysql query

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

I have a webform populated by mysql objects.

This is my current webform:

```
if($statement_opc->execute())
{
    $numero_opciones = 0;
    $result_opc = $statement_opc->fetchAll();
    foreach($result_opc as $row_opc)
    {
        if ($row_opc['producto'] == $row['id']) {
            $numero_opciones = $numero_opciones + 1;
            $output .= '
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox"  id="opcion'.$row["id"].'"  value="">'.$row_opc['nombre'].' (+ $'.$row_opc['precio'].')</label>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="opcion_nombre'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row_opc["nombre"].'" />
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="opcion_precio'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row_opc["precio"].'" />
            ';

        }
    }
}
$cat_anterior = $row['id_cat'];

$output .= '
    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity' . $row["id"] .'" class="form-control" value="1" style="text-align:right;"/>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row["name"].'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row["price"].'" />

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-bt style="text-align:LEFT">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-number" name="restar"  id="'.$row["id"].'" " >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
            </button>
        </span>

        <span class="input-group-btn style="text-align:RIGHT">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number-sumar" name="sumar" id="'.$row["id"].'"">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="add_to_cart" id="'.$row["id"].'" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success form-control add_to_cart" value="Add to Cart" />

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    ';
}

//echo $titulo;
echo $output;
```

And this is the jQuery function that gets all webform objects:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_to_cart', function(){

    var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var product_name = $('#name'+product_id+'').val();
    var product_price = $('#price'+product_id+'').val();
    var product_quantity = $('#quantity'+product_id).val();
    var product_opcion_nombre = $('#opcion_nombre'+product_id).val();
    var product_opcion_precio = $('#opcion_precio'+product_id).val();
    var action = "add";
    if(product_quantity > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{product_id:product_id, product_name:product_name, product_price:product_price, product_quantity:product_quantity,action:action},
            success:function(data)
            {
                load_cart_data();
                alert("Item has been Added into Cart");
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("lease Enter Number of Quantity");
    }

});
```

As you may see, I get all the objets by its product_id value, declared in the form using the appendix **.$row['id']**

Each webform item may have or not some other objects, in this case the new objects are checkboxes populated by another MySQL query.
I mean this part of the webform:

```
$numero_opciones = 0;
$result_opc = $statement_opc->fetchAll();
foreach($result_opc as $row_opc)
{
    if ($row_opc['producto'] == $row['id']) {
        $numero_opciones = $numero_opciones + 1;
        $output .= '
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox"  id="opcion'.$row["id"].'"  value="">'.$row_opc['nombre'].' (+ $'.$row_opc['precio'].')</label>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="opcion_nombre'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row_opc["nombre"].'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="opcion_precio'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row_opc["precio"].'" />
            ';
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to get the needed value from the first foreach loop, but I don't know how to declare the checkboxes id to get the needed values for the checked checkboxes to be used later in the jQuery function.

This is what I have so far, but only getting if the first checkbox is checked or not, not able to get the status of all existing checkboxes:

```
if ($('#opcion'+product_id).is(":checked"))
{
    // it is checked
    alert ('checked');
}
else
{
    alert ('unchecked');
}
```

I know that it is not easy to understand what am I asking, but please, be patient and ask for more detail information about my question.

Comment: Use a `.class` selector to get an array of all checked boxes. And cleanup your code, the indentation and spacing is wack ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat, thank you  for your comment. I am trying to solve this issue for two days, and I am not sure to understand your proposal. I would appreciate a practical proposal based on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `.class` selector instead of an `#id` selector in jquery will return all elements that match. So, on all your checkboxes, add a special class to them like so:

```
'<input type="checkbox" id="opcion'.$row["id"].'"  class="opcion_cbox"  value="">'
```

That way when you do the following with jquery, you will have all the checked checkboxes to use:

```
var checked_boxes = $(".opcion_cbox:checkbox:checked");
```

Or you can loop through them all with something along this line:

```
$(".opcion_cbox:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
    // do something with $(this) checkbox in a loop
});
```

---

If you wanted to get that 'row id' so you can reference other elements on the page with that id, you could use `data-variables`.

```
'<input type="checkbox" 
    id="opcion'.$row["id"].'" 
    class="opcion_cbox" 
    data-rowid="'. $row["id"] .'" 
    value="">'
```

..

```
$(".opcion_cbox:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
    
    var rowid = $(this).data('rowid');

    var nombre = $("#opcion_nombre"+ rowid).val();
    var precio = $("#opcion_precio"+ rowid).val();

});
```

---

Or more cleanly you could just put those values as data variables themselves from php:

```
'<input type="checkbox" 
    id="opcion'.$row["id"].'" 
    class="opcion_cbox" 
    data-nombre="'. $row_opc["nombre"] .'" 
    data-precio="'. $row_opc["precio"] .'" 
    value="">'
// be sure to escape any double-quotes in nombre/precio
```

..

```
$(".opcion_cbox:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
    
    var nombre = $(this).data('nombre');
    var precio = $(this).data('precio');

});
```

---

Going from there you can do all sorts with each checked box. You could loop on ALL your option boxes if you wish instead, and then check inside the loop if the box is checked (thats if you need to perform something with all boxes, and not just the checked ones).

Comment: I have implemented your proposal and it is working fine, it detects when the checkbox is checked. But now what I need is to get the vaues for the checked box items like this:x      <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="opcion_nombre'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row_opc["nombre"].'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="opcion_precio'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$row_opc["precio"].'" />

Comment: Check the edit, I was adding that when you commented ;) Also added a different way to pass those values to jquery instead of using the hidden inputs (unless you need the hidden inputs for form POST).

Comment: Very nice, it is working, very happy after 2 days of tries. I have detected an issue, may be it is not difficult to solve. At the moment there are at least 10 store items, and some of them have checkboxes. Every item has a add_to_cart button, the issue is that when clicking on the button at any of the items, the jquery function $(".opcion_cbox:checkbox:checked").each(function() is reading every checkbox at the page, not only the checkboxes from the selected item

Comment: That... sounds a bit beyond the scope of this question. But yeah, something may be leaking or something else is triggering deep somewhere. Hard to know for sure from your description. The selector should* only be of checked boxes (ones with `checked="checked"` set for them).